# Timeseries Prediction using Dilated Causal Convolutions with Tensorflow 2.0

Tags: python, tensorflow, shapes

my task is to predict the next timeseries value depending on the 200 timesteps before (similar to the WaveNet), using Tensorflow 2.0.0 and Python 3.6.
I have a problem with mismatching shapes of my training data. I get the following error message:

> ValueError: A target array with shape (495, 1, 1) was passed for an output of shape (None, 200, 1) while using as loss `mean_squared_error`. This loss expects targets to have the same shape as the output.

My code:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import tensorflow.keras as k
import numpy as np

batch_size = 495
epochs = 5
learning_rate = 0.001
dilations = 7
seq_length=200

class TCNBlock(k.Model):
    def __init__(self, dilation, seq_length):
        super(TCNBlock, self).__init__()
        self.seq_length = seq_length

        self.convolution0 = k.layers.Conv1D(8, kernel_size=4, strides=1, padding='causal', dilation_rate=dilation)
        self.BatchNorm0 = k.layers.BatchNormalization(momentum=0.6)
        self.relu0 = k.layers.ReLU()
        self.dropout0 = k.layers.Dropout(rate=0.2)

        self.convolution1 = k.layers.Conv1D(8, kernel_size=4, strides=1, padding='causal', dilation_rate=dilation)
        self.BatchNorm1 = k.layers.BatchNormalization(momentum=0.6)
        self.relu1 = k.layers.ReLU()
        self.dropout1 = k.layers.Dropout(rate=0.2)
        self.residual = k.layers.Conv1D(1, kernel_size=1, padding='same')


    def build_block(self, dilation, training=False):
        inputs = k.Input(shape=(200, 1))
        output_layer1 = self.convolution0(inputs)
        output_layer2 = self.BatchNorm0(output_layer1)
        output_layer3 = self.relu0(output_layer2)
        output_layer4 = self.dropout0(output_layer3, training)
        output_layer5 = self.convolution1(output_layer4)
        output_layer6 = self.BatchNorm1(output_layer5)
        output_layer7 = self.relu1(output_layer6)
        output = self.dropout1(output_layer7, training)
        residual = self.residual(output)
        outputs = k.layers.add([inputs, residual])

        return k.models.Model(inputs=inputs, outputs=outputs)


def build_model():
    mdl = k.models.Sequential()
    for dilation in range(dilations):
        dilation_actual = int(np.power(2, dilation))
        block = TCNBlock(dilation_actual, seq_length).build_block(dilation_actual)
        mdl.add(block)
    return mdl


Model_complete = build_model()
opt = k.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=learning_rate)
Model_complete.compile(loss='mean_squared_error', optimizer=opt, metrics=["accuracy"])

# Train Model
training_process = Model_complete.fit(x_train, y_train, epochs=epochs, verbose=1, batch_size=495, validation_split=0.1)
```

My data has the following shape:

```
x_train.shape = (495, 200, 1) 
y_train.shape = (495, 1, 1)
```

I would appreciate any help and suggestions.
Thank you!

Comment: `seq_length` is missing, so I can't run your example

Comment: seq_length is 200. I added it in the Code now

Comment: Your network has as output layer the shape `(None, 200, 1)`, but you want the last layer to be `(None, 1, 1)`.

Comment: Yes thats right. I'm new to python and tensorflow so I don't see the mistake here. I thougth that the self.residual layer would add all of the 200 values because there is only 1 filter?

Comment: I think you got a few things confused here. The general shape is `(batch, dimensions, filters)`. If you apply a convolution with 1 filter the result is `(batch, dimensions, 1)`
and not `(batch, 1, 1)`.

Comment: Ok, thanks. So I have to find out what the meaning of those 200 values of the output layer is. Because my model should predict the next value of the timeserie data which is the input of my model

Comment: I would rather say that you have to restructure your model in such a way that the output layer has the shape of (batch, 1, 1) and you can train on your labels

Comment: Can't replicate the error you encountered. The training is working just fine with the code you provided.

Answer (score 2):

The important step in `Time Series Analysis Prediction` is to prepare the Data such that the Model makes the respective `Prediction`.

The `Function` which performs that `Important Step` is shown below:

```
def multivariate_data(dataset, target, start_index, end_index, history_size,
                      target_size, step, single_step=False):
  data = []
  labels = []

  start_index = start_index + history_size
  if end_index is None:
    end_index = len(dataset) - target_size

  for i in range(start_index, end_index):
    indices = range(i-history_size, i, step)
    data.append(dataset[indices])

    if single_step:
      labels.append(target[i+target_size])
    else:
      labels.append(target[i:i+target_size])

  return np.array(data), np.array(labels)
```

The important arguments of the above function which needs explanation is `history_size` and `target_size`.

In your case, `history_size` will be 200 and `target_size` will be 1.

I have a sincere suggestion to you (no offence please. Intention is to genuinely to help you). As you are relatively new to `Tensorflow` I request you to go through the [Time Series Tutorial](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/structured_data/time_series) given in the Tensorflow Website, which is implemented using `LSTMs`, understand it completely and then try implementing it using `Dilated Convolutions`.

Hope this helps. Happy Learning!